# division of polynomials and remainder theorem

Tags: polynomials

If a binomial $p(x)$ is divided by $x-3$ we get remainder $5$ and if divided by $x-5$ we get remainder $3$. What will be the remainder if we divide it by $(x-3)(x-5)$?

Answer (score 2):

$$P(x)=(x-3)(x-5)Q(x)+ax+b$$
$$P(3)=3a+b=5$$
$$P(5)=5a+b=3$$
$$a=-1, b=8$$
$$\therefore remainder = -x + 8$$

Comment: As $p(x)$ is supposed to be binomial, you may as well start with let $p(x) = ax+b$...